# Scapy sniff the packet multiple times?

Tags: python, scapy

I am using Scapy to capture packets by using the following code

```
from scapy.all import *

def verify(p):
     p.display()

sniff(prn=verify, iface="lo")
```

The sniff function captures every packet multiple times.
For example, if I have a DNS query packet, this packet will display two times.
How can make The sniff function to capture each packet only single time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  Scapy sees the packets on the loopback interface both when they "leave" and when they "arrive."  So everything is duplicated with no distinction, because loopback is a special interface.  Perhaps you should yourself just skip every second packet.

It was reported as a bug once, but rejected: https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/issues/887/sniff-sends-packets-twice